# Loading all javascript files in the footer in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using Nodejs with ejs plugin. I have `header.ejs` and `footer.ejs` partials. In my footer I have about `<script src = "home.js">`,`<script src = "profile.js">` etc for different pages.

Most of these pages do not depend on each other and does not need the script file for another page to load. But I was just thinking about this today and thought this would be really inefficient. Would I be right in thinking so? Most websites I inspect also have multiple scripts loaded in page, some of which seems unnecessary.

If this is not the correct way to do it, how would I load page specific scripts only?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JS files have unique names

```
  <script src="<%= jsfile %>">
```

And in your Node code you can pass the `jsfile` variable as an option

```
html = ejs.render(file, {jsfile: "home.js"});
```

Comment: How would I implement multiple files? If I want to load 2 scripts in a file?